# Android webview takes screenshot only from top of the page

Tags: android, android-webview, webpage-screenshot

I am doing a very simple task of taking a screenshot from my webView into a Bitmap... I do it like this:

```
webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getDrawingCache(false));
webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
webView.draw(canvas);
```

The problem is that the final bitmap is always showing the top of my web page content! I actually need it to take the screenshot from where I have scrolled the content but this is not simply happening! I have been searching the net for two hours now but no one else seems to have a similar problem. any idea what could have gone wrong?

Comment: Do you explicitly want to display the bitmap inside the webView? Or are you doing this just to see what the bitmap shows? If so, try creating a 2nd visible view where you draw the canvas/bitmap.

Comment: @tobyUCT I will later save the bitmap as a png file on sdcard. I actually want the screenshot from where the user has scrolled.

Comment: Same issue here. If the WebView is scrolled down far enough then I would only get a blank screen in that bitmap. That's obviously an unfortunate bug in WebView.

Answer (score 3):

I guess, this is on Lollipop? If so, make sure you call WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw() ([doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw())) before your first call to `setContentView()` that inflates a layout with WebView.

Comment: Nope, not a lollipop thing... I'm testing on android 2.3 and 4.0.2 and have this weird problem.

Comment: OK, then what height does your WebView have? You need to set the height of WebView to `wrap_content` and put it inside a ScrollView. Then you'll get a WebView tall enough to fit your web page, and drawing into a bitmap should now output the entire page.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need the last 2 lines.Just drop them.

```
webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);  
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webView.getDrawingCache(false));  
webView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

will return the very bitmap you need, from what I've seen.

Comment: That works for me, though those APIs are deprecated. Not sure if they are ever planning to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and solved it the follwoing way:

First call `WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw()` before `setContentView()`. Then take the screenshot over the whole content of the webview and then crop the bitmap to the actual view size with the desired scroll offset:

```
// the minimum bitmap height needs to be the view height
int bitmapHeight = (webView.getMeasuredHeight() < webView.getContentHeight())
         ? webView.getContentHeight() : webView.getMeasuredHeight();

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
         webView.getMeasuredWidth(), bitmapHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
webView.draw(canvas);

// prevent IllegalArgumentException for createBitmap: 
// y + height must be <= bitmap.height()
int scrollOffset = (scrollTo + webView.getMeasuredHeight() > bitmap.getHeight())
         ? bitmap.getHeight() : scrollTo;

Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createBitmap(
         bitmap, 0, scrollOffset, bitmap.getWidth(), webView.getMeasuredHeight());
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

> First, add webview inside a LinearLayout..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layoutWeb"
    >
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webview"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

> Second, initialize views inside onCreate() method...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutWeb);
    ....
 }
```

> Third, write a function to take a screenshot... Here, **View v1 = webLayout;** specifies the view which we want to take a screenshot of.

```
public void takeScreenshot() {
  try{   
      View v1 = webLayout;
      v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
      Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
      v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
      String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/screenshot.jpg";
      File imageFile = new File(mPath);
      FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
      int quality = 100;
      bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
      outputStream.flush();
      outputStream.close();
 } catch(Throwable e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

This takes a screenshot of the part that is covered by webLayout. Scroll up down to focus on other areas and take screenshot of the webView.