# take screenshort WebView android

Tags: android, webview

I just create a simple WebView and take screenshot but the result is not satisfied. Here is a simple code I wrote:

```
val webView = WebView(context)
var content = this.getContent() // this.getContent() is demo html string
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, content, "text/HTML", "UTF-8", null);
webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)
        SystemClock.sleep(1000)
    var data = webView.toBitmap()
    var path = applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + "/sample.jpg"
    var file = File(path)
    file.writeBitmap(data, Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100)
    print("\n absolutePath ${file.path}")

    }
}
```

/// extension

```
fun View.toBitmap(): Bitmap {
    this.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    print("\n measuredWidth: ${this.measuredWidth}, measuredHeight: ${this.measuredHeight}")
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.measuredWidth, this.measuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    this.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}

fun Bitmap.toByteArray(): ByteArrayOutputStream {
    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    this.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream)
    return stream
}

fun File.writeBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap, format: Bitmap.CompressFormat, quality: Int) {
    try {
        var fout = FileOutputStream(this.path)
        bitmap.compress(format, quality, fout)
        fout.flush()
        fout.close()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

[image]

I want to take the whole picture of my webview not just a visible part. So what can i do with this code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android webview takes screenshot only from top of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295237/android-webview-takes-screenshot-only-from-top-of-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I reproduced

```
fun loadWebView() {
        var content = this.getContent()
        var webView = WebView(this)
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, content, "text/HTML", "UTF-8", null)
        webView.setInitialScale(1)
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
        webView.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            print("\n=======> enabled scrolled <=========")
            WebView.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw()
        }
        setContentView(webView)
        print("\n ///////////////// webview setted /////////////////")

        webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                Handler().postDelayed( {
                    print("OS Version: ${android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT}")
                    print("\n ================ webview completed ==============")
                    var result = saveWebView(webView)
                    print("result $result")
                }, 1000)

            }
        }
    }
```

and to save it to file

```
fun saveWebView(webView: WebView): Boolean {
        var data = webView.toBitmap()
        var path = this.applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(null).toString() + "/sample.jpg"
        var file = File(path)
        file.writeBitmap(data, Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100)
        return true
    }
```

Here is the result I get.
[image]

But I am wondering why I can not convert WebView to Bitmap without use method setContentView(webView)?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this can answer your question
[Android webview takes screenshot only from top of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31295237/android-webview-takes-screenshot-only-from-top-of-the-page)

You're changing the measured sized of the webview and you should complete the draw cycle (measure/layout/draw)

Also tell the webview not to optimize memory usage
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw()

Try to layout the view after measure and before draw like

```
fun View.toBitmap(): Bitmap {

    this.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    print("\n measuredWidth: ${this.measuredWidth}, measuredHeight: ${this.measuredHeight}")
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.measuredWidth, this.measuredHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

    this.layout(0, 0, this.measuredWidth, this.measuredHeight)

    // For webView
    (this as? WebView)?.enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw()

    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    this.draw(canvas)
    return bitmap
}
```

Actually, I've never tested this on WebView but it works fine on everything I've tested

Comment: From Ref : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#enableSlowWholeDocumentDraw()
it said this is a public static method so I tested it, it didn't work. Do you have any snippet, so i can have idea.

Comment: I guess the linked question might have some information, as I said I've never done this on WebView

Comment: okay i got it.  so do you have any suggestion to capture html content into bitmap?